# How to store Map in Solr document?

Tags: dictionary, solr

I am trying to add `HashMap` into Solr document. I have gone through Solr documentation but didn't get exactly what I am trying to do.

Solr supports list but I need `Map` stored in document.

Example:

```
 {
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "Foo bar",
    "social":{
             "facebook":"facebookid",
             "twitter":"twitterid"
             }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you need a map as your. Solr documents included the one in your example can be managed using SolrDocument, SolrInputDocument,  or SolrInputDocumentList.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to flatten the structure before indexing it, as that will make queries, facets and most other features easier to use (as you won't have to use any blockjoins, child/parent-support, etc.).

Index the content as:

```
{
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "Foo bar",
    "social_facebook": "facebookid",
    "social_twitter": "twitterid"
}
```

.. and recreate the map if necessary (it usually isn't) in your query layer (which would vary depending on the language and library you're using).